# php mysql Invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql

i have table steps with it's sort_id(**id**)(A_I), **page_id** and sort number (**sort**), i need  add new row with the same page_id and max sort of group id and page_id

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `steps` (`sort`, `page_id`)
VALUES
    (
        MAX(`sort`) + 1,
        (
            SELECT
                page_id
            FROM
                steps
            WHERE
                `id` = '1'
        )
    )");
```

and i receive error

```
[Err] 1111 - Invalid use of group function
```

i need like this

```
INSERT INTO `steps` (`sort`, `page_id`)
VALUES
    (
        SELECT
            Max(s1.sort) + 1 AS sort,
            s2.page_id AS page_id
        FROM
            steps AS s1,
            steps AS s2
        WHERE
            s2.id = '1'
    )
```

but [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Comment: _“and max sort of group id and page_id”_ – well, then _select_ that value, instead of just putting an aggregate function name randomly into a query where it does not belong.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing the `select` part of the subquery:

```
insert into `steps`(`sort`, `page_id`)
values
(
    SELECT
        max(`sort`) +1,
        page_id
    FROM
        steps
    WHERE
        `id` = '1'
    group by
        page_id
)
```

It's late, but this should either work, or put you onto the right path to get it working.

Lastly, you should really move away from `mysql_query` functions. Have a look at [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. It is safer, portable to other databases and if you are just learning this stuff now, you may as well learn on the current technolgy.

Edit:

Based on the comment to the other answer, this will be closer to what you are looking for:

```
insert into `steps`(`sort`, `page_id`)
values
(
    SELECT
        (select max(`sort`) from steps) +1,
        page_id
    FROM
        steps
    WHERE
        `id` = '1'
    group by
        page_id
)
```

Comment: i need like insert into `steps`(`sort`, `page_id`)
values
(
    SELECT
        max(`sort`) +1,
        page_id
    FROM
        steps
    WHERE
        `id` = '1'
    group by
        page_id
)

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `steps` (`sort`, `page_id`)(SELECT MAX(`sort`) + 1,page_id FROM steps WHERE `id` = '1')");
```

Comment: i need max sort .. id can be any not only 1 but they have the same page_id

Comment: i need like this INSERT INTO `steps` (`sort`, `page_id`) VALUES(
SELECT
Max(s1.sort)+1 as sort,
s2.page_id as page_id
FROM
steps AS s1 ,
steps AS s2
WHERE
s2.id = '1'
)

Comment: Remove the VALUES word because the sub query statement return the scalat value so no need to VALUES    insert into steps (sort,page_id )  (SELECT Max(s1.sort)+1 as sort, s2.page_id as page_id FROM steps AS s1, steps AS s2 WHERE s2.id = '1')   use this

Comment: insert into steps (sort,page_id )  (SELECT Max(s1.sort)+1 as sort, s2.page_id as page_id FROM steps AS s1, steps AS s2 WHERE s2.id = '1')